# How do the curly braces work in this Ruby Split line

Tags: ruby, regex

I have been recommended the following line of code to use on a text file:

```
arr = str.split(/\n{2,}/).map { |s| s.split(/\n/) }
```

Am trying to understand how the:

```
(/\n{2,}/)
```

Part is working and exactly what it does.

Comment: `\n{2,}` means match two or more newline characters. Sometimes you will see this written `\n\n+`.

Comment: In other words, in this case, the curly braces are part of Ruby's regular expression syntax and have nothing to do with Ruby's usual uses of curly braces, which are: 1) to mark the beginning and end of a code block, and 2) to enclose a hash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The leading and trailing `/` mark the beginning and the end of a regular expression. `\n` will match any single newline. `{2,}` after a symbol (in this case `\n`) will match any occurrence of the symbol repeated two or more times, in this case two or more consecutive newlines. Had it been `\n{3,6}`, it would match any consecutive newlines repeated between 3 and 6 times.